Consistency of first-order Peano arithmetic
I recently found a proof on Wikipedia that Peano arithmetic together with the axiom of its inconsistency is a consistent system if $PA$ is. It goes as follows: "Now, the consistency of $PA$ implies the consistency of $PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)$. Indeed, if $PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ was inconsistent, then $PA$ alone would prove $\neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)\to 0=1$, and a reductio ad absurdum in $PA$ would produce a proof of $\operatorname{Con}(PA)$. By Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, $PA$ would be inconsistent.
Therefore, assuming that $PA$ is consistent, $PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ is consistent too."
By a similar line of reasoning $PA + \operatorname{Con}(PA)$ is consistent if $PA$ is. Because since PA doesnt prove its own inconsistency it must have a model in which PA
is consistent. And the same goes for any formal
system which is consistent X. But now, letting X=$(PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA))$
we get $$(PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)) + \operatorname{Con}(PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA))$$ must be consistent if $PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ that is if $PA$ is by a similar argument as that applied to $PA$, now applied to $PA + \neg \operatorname{Con}(PA)$. But this is clearly inconsistent as it equals $PA + \neg\operatorname{Con}(PA) + \operatorname{Con}(PA)$ but the proof says it must be consistent so $PA$ must be inconsistent by contraposition. Where's the error in my reasoning?

This is a site for the computing software Mathematica. You want [math.SE].

You forgot a $\neg$.

The first error is here:

By a similar line of reasoning PA + Con(PA) is consistent if PA is.

I mean, the conclusion is actually true (PA + Con(PA) is actually consistent), but it doesn't follow from a "similar" line of reasoning.
The actual error is here:

But now (PA + ¬Con(PA)) + Con(PA + ¬Con(PA)) must be consistent

X being consistent does not imply that X + Con(X) is consistent.

$X$ beeing consistent implies  $X+Con(X)$ beeing consistent. If $X$ is first order theory  and as such, if $X$ doesn't proves $Con(X)$ then $X+Con(x)$ is consistent (because has a model).

@Antares The step "then X + Con(X) is consistent (because it has a model)" doesn't follow. How did you get that? In fact, X = PA + ¬Con(PA) (as in the original question) is a nice counter-example to this claim: in this case X is consistent but X + Con(X) is inconsistent.

In any first order logic theory X and for any sentence $\phi$ we get  $X \models \phi$ to be equivalent $X \vdash \phi$ (where $X \models \phi$ means "in every model of $X$, $\phi$ is true").  So, as $\neg(X \vdash Con(X))$, we get that  there's a model of $X$ in which  $Con(x)$ is true. This model is in the same moment model of $X+Con(X)$ so that theory is consistent.  You example isn't counterexample to my claim,  $X+Con(X)$  is consistent here, it has some model which means that it isn't inconsistent.

@Antares " So, as ¬(⊢()), we get that there's a model of  in which () is true." You are missing a negation there. It should read: "[...] a model of X in which Con(X) is false".

Have added a reason for why i think your last statement is false

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm You seem to have added "Because since PA doesnt prove its own inconsistency it must have a model in which PA is consistent. And the same goes for any formal system which is consistent X." This last statement doesn't work. A consistent system X may prove its own inconsistency. Your own X = PA + ¬Con(PA) is an example of that: it proves that PA is inconsistent, and therefore that X is also inconsistent.

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm I think what you're implicitly assuming is that consistency implies that a theory doesn't prove false theorems. But that is not true. That would require soundness, not just consistency. Soundness is a stronger property than consistency. PA is sound, but X = PA + ¬Con(PA) is not sound.

You say the conclusion PA + Con(PA) actually does follow from a different line of reasoning but not in general that if X is consistent then X+Con(X) is consistent. Why does the different line of reasoning work for PA but not X in general?

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm We have a model of PA + Con(PA), namely the set of natural numbers N with standard + and * operations. In that model PA is true and Con(PA) is also true. Whereas X + Con(X) does not have a model, so that argument doesn't work. We know that X has a model, but in that model Con(X) is actually false (because Con(PA) is false, and Con(X) is an even stronger statement), so it doesn't work as a model for X + Con(X).

Why is it that everything can be proved from a contradiction (and hence an inconsistent system must be unsound) yet not everything can be proved from a falsehood (hence unsound implying inconsistency)? I thought the principle of explosion followed from the law that p -> q if p is false?

Similarily Godel’s theorem incompleteness theorem as I understand it finds a theorem G which says it can’t be proved which is thus either unprovable or provable and false whereupon it is concluded that the system is unsound hence inconsistent

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm You can prove p -> q if you have already proved that p is false. It's not enough that p is false if you haven't proved it. If you have proved both p and "p is false", then you have a contradiction.

What about this argument: X proves its own inconsistency yet its inconsistency
is not logically valid since it's false (if PA is consistent) thus there must be models in which X+Con(X) is true

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm Sorry I just don't understand this argument. I have no idea how you get that a model of X+Con(X) must exist from the premises you just stated. In any case, the premises are true, the conclusion is false, so something must be wrong.

But wouldn’t it follow from the rule p->p->q implies p->q and the fact from Godel’s completeness theorem that what a system can prove is exactly the inferences from its axioms that if T proves T proves consistency then T proves consistency ie if a system proves its own inconsistency it must be inconsistent?

@Nikolairiberskånstrøm My advice is that you have to be super careful with the details and theorem assumptions. p -> p -> q is not the same as T |= (T |= q). Gödel's incompleteness theorems have certain assumptions. Etc. You can't just throw out some vague argument by intuitive analogy and expect it hold up.
